# How can I disable auto-rotate on my phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, auto-rotation

I have a Droid 1 now running CM7.

Previously in CM6, there was an option to prevent the phone from auto-rotating (a rotation lock of sorts).  The only time it would rotate was when I slid out the keyboard.  I can't seem to find the option in CM7 (it might have been removed). Is there any other way to replicate this behavior (or am I blind and missing the feature in CM7)?

Comment: When did you flash 7?  I can't get [Cyanogen's site](http://www.cyanogenmod.com) to load and ROM Manager keeps timing out on the download!  This waiting thing sucks!

Comment: @JonnyP I flashed Monday.  It looks like their website is down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `Menu -> Settings -> Display -> Auto-rotate screen` - This option should disable screen rotation throughout the system.
2. `Menu -> Settings -> CyanogenMod settings -> Display -> Rotate 180 degrees` - This option disables the "upside-down" rotation only.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking under CM settings, not the Display settings.

Answer (score 6):

if you need easy access to it then

Menu -> Settings -> CyanogenMod settings -> Display -> Interface -> Notification power widget - > Widget buttons -> Toggle Orientation

will add a widget on the notification menu that lets you enable or disable rotation. just about the only time it seems useful is if you are lying on your side and you want the phone to stay in landscape, but it sure is convenient for that.